# Resizing a multidimensional Python list of lists

Tags: python, list

Have been searching here and many other places, but not finding what I need, so I wonder if some kind soul can help me?

Given the four-dimensional list:

```
tv = [[[[0 for x in range(2)]]] for c in range(7)]
```

How can I resize it so that I can do

```
tv[0][1][0][0] = 'Hello'

print tv
```

Comment: Why don't you use `numpy`?

Comment: I don't understand, why don't you just do `tv[0][0][0][1] = 'Hello'`

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by _resize_? Also, you have a suspicious-unicode quote character wrapping your `Hello`

Comment: Let's see...I don't believe `Numpy` can do what I need, above what native python can do. I didn't do `tv[0][0][0][1] = 'Hello'` because that's not what I want to do. `Resize` means to adjust the list size. There is no suspicious-unicode character wrapping my `Hello` in my actual code; what you're seeing is the result of a copy-and-paste from one editor to that of stackoverflow.

Comment: I'm still not quiet following you on your resize. In your question, you assign the string `Hello` in a place of your list. However, it's indexing out-of-bounds. Can you provide your current output with your expected output?

Comment: I think that something like 'rotate' or 'reindex' might be a more accurate term for what you want to do.  Can you post what you want the tv list to look like?  It starts as 7 x 1 x 1 x 2, and you obviously want the second dimension to have a length greater than 1, but beyond that it is impossible to determine how you want the dimensions distributed.

Comment: Are you trying to unlist the list, so it has less dimensions?

Comment: @Matthew, yes I want the second dimension to have a length greater than 1, but I want to do it dynamically, so that the list starts out as 7 x 1 x 1 x 2 and end up as 7 x 2 x 1 x 2 after I (resize | re-index | change | grow | morph ... pick one) the list.

Comment: I start out with this list declaration:

tv = [[[[0 for x in range(2)]]] for c in range(7)]

I want the following line to eventually work, after I modify the tv list:

tv[0][1][0][0] = 'Hello'

How do I modify the list to accomplish that?

Comment: Yes, @Miket25, it indexes out-of-bounds, which is why I stated "...so that I can do" in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to combine some dimension. Probably way easier to do in `numpy` but you can do something like this

```
tv = [[[[0 for x in range(2)]]] for c in range(7)]

tv = [tv[x]+tv[x+1] if x <= 5 else tv[-1:] for x in range(0,len(tv),2)]

tv[0][1][0][0] = 'Hello'

[[[[0, 0]], [['Hello', 0]]], [[[0, 0]], [[0, 0]]], [[[0, 0]], [[0, 0]]], [[[[0, 0]]]]]
```

You didn't specify they 4D values you want it shaped to, but you could just modify that line

Comment: So, when I do tv[0][0][0][0] = 'Hello' it outputs [[[['Hello', 0]]], [[[0, 0]]], [[[0, 0]]], [[[0, 0]]], [[[0, 0]]], [[[0, 0]]], [[[0, 0]]]] and when I do tv[0][1][0][0] = 'Hello' I want it to output [[[[0, 0]]], [[['Hello', 0]]], [[[0, 0]]], [[[0, 0]]], [[[0, 0]]], [[[0, 0]]], [[[0, 0]]]] (your example is missing some dimensions)

Comment: My example isn't missing a dimension, you're not being clear about what you want, because `tv[0][1][0][0]` is not a valid index for the 4d list you just provided in that comment and in the question

Comment: And so, the goal is to MAKE it valid. That's what I want.

Comment: For example, in C, let's say I have the following declaration: char *ptr; but I eventually want this to work: ptr[5] = 'h'; Obviously, without something in between the two lines, this will fail, similar to the Python example I provided. So, a C solution for my new example might be ptr = (char *) malloc(25); in between the lines. Ta-da! That's what I'm after. So, what do I need to do to make tv[0][1][0][0] = 'Hello' work, given tv = [[[[0 for x in range(2)]]] for c in range(7)] ? (BTW, your formatting / markup page doesn't seem to help us Mac-ites, or I would have formatted these lines better.)